# SSL: Do certificate authorities know anything about a website's users?

Tags: tls

I'm wondering about how much sense this sentence makes."I'm using a self signed certificate because i don't want trusted authorities to learn anything about my users". CA's just sign the server's certificate with their private key they don't need to know anything about the users, right?

Answer (score 7):

During the certificate validation the client might contact the CA controlled OCSP responder to check for certificate revocation. Thus, while the CA does not know what exactly the client visits (i.e. does not see traffic and could not decrypt it if it sees it) it might get at least an association between the clients IP address and the certificate of the visited site.

The way around this is OCSP stapling where the server already provides the (CA signed) OCSP response and the client does not  have to access the CA. This is also recommended for performance since the client does not need to create an additional connection for OCSP lookup and wait for the result.

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20409/for-ssl-certs-is-some-sort-of-connection-to-the-issuing-ca-or-other-network

Answer (score 1):

Certificate Authorities sign the certificate and not the private key.

They can't decrypt the data transmitted between the server and a client, so they can't know anything about your users.